# Selenium test in jenkins is failed (Timed out after seconds waiting for presence of element located), but locally it works fine

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

I have such problem. My tests successfully passed in IDEA, but Jenkins fails them and such error message appears in build log: "Timed out after 100 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.xpath: .//div[3]//div[4]//a" This element located in the bottom of the page, but in IDEA I have no problems with locating and interaction with it and webdriver automatically scrolls down to it. So, I've tried to replace this selector, I've tried to increase wait of this element, but I still get this error message appeared in build log. Have anybody experienced in this issue?!

Comment: I'm actually curious about the answers. I observed the exact same problem. When executed on integrtion environnement, Selenium tests tended to fail randomly.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues many times when I run my scripts through Jenkins on remote sandbox machine. What I did was just before the script would locate for that element, I have put 5 seconds of **Explicit Wait** to check if the problem lies with DOM Problem(UI is loaded but background functionality still in progress of loading). Fortunately, mine worked. Hope it helps in your case. If you can provide some sample code, I may help more than this :)

Comment: So, I have such code in my page object for this button: 
@FindBy(xpath = ".//div[3]//div[4]//a")
WebElement moreButton;

public void clickMoreButtonUniverCard(WebDriver driver) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 500);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//div[3]//div[4]//a")));
        moreButton.click();
    }

Comment: And such code for this method in test:<br/>

pageNavigatorHomeFsm.clickMoreButtonUniverCard(driver); //this is my method, where jenkins couldn't find element
System.out.println("div(.description.collapsed) is " + pageNavigatorHomeFsm.isElementPresent(driver));

Comment: I would suggest you to try following things
* Put Thread.sleep() of atleast 10 seconds, before moreButton.click(); or Fluent Wait, to know if the problem lies with DOM.

* If you are using Jenkins to run your scripts on a different machine, check the browser version of your local and that of jenkins machine to be same. Many times problem lies with browser versions only.

* Instead of giving xpath to 'position base', you can try giving it on basis of text or class(//a[contains(text(),'---')]).

* Instead of .isElementPresent(driver)), try findElements() or element(xx).shouldBeVisible();